# How to create test Postgres db in flask-tesing

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I am using flask-testing to do some unit tests on a Postgres application. According to [doc](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing) , I have following code.

```
from flask_testing import TestCase
from src.game.models import db
from src import create_app    
class BaseTest(TestCase):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://demo:demo@postgres:5432/test_db'
    TESTING = True

    def create_app(self):
        # pass in test configuration
        return create_app(self)

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
```

Of course I got this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:
> database "test_db" does not exist

I do have a database `postgresql://demo:demo@postgres:5432/demo` which is my production database.

How can I create `test_db` in this `BaseTest` class? I am using Python 3.6 and latest flask and flask-sqlalchemy. Thank you very much.

Comment: As you use sqlalchemy, you could use sqllite for testing.

Comment: If I have a Postgres specific feature, I cannot use sqlite

Comment: Either create the database outside the test or include SQL in the test that does `CREATE DATABASE test_db` and then drops it afterwards.